# Sending strings through html textbox using java

Tags: java, browser, automation

i want to make a console program in java that will send the input that it gets from the user, to an HTML POST form. sort of an auto-fill program.
i only need a simple direction. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html with System.exec call or you will need to write something like this:

```
String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/index.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.flush();

String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

This example was taken from [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Comment: The code gives full html page output to the console,  which I don't need..  But that's good enough to get me going.  Ty

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is
> entirely up to you.  Primarily it is for automating web applications
> for testing purposes,  but is certainly not limited to just that.
> Boring web-based administration tasks can  (and should!) also be
> automated as well.
>
> Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken  (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part
> of their browser.  It is also the core technology in countless other
> browser automation tools,  APIs and frameworks.